# Clarification on passing a pointer by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

This is kind of silly, but I can't really explain why this is happening. As an exercise, I wanted to reverse a singly-linkedlist and I did this by defining the method:

```
class solution {
    void reverseLinkedList(Node*& head) {
      Node* curr = head;
      Node* prev = NULL;
      while (curr != NULL) {
        Node* _next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = _next;
      }
      head = prev;
}
```

In my main function, I make the call

```
solution s;
s.reverseLinkedList(head);

Node* iterator = head;
while (iterator != NULL) {
    std::cout<<iterator->data<<std::endl;
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

Where I previously defined my head pointer to some linkedlist. The while loop is for printing my linkedlist and the function does it job. This only worked after I passed the head node by reference; I initially tried to pass Node* head instead of Node*& head in the beginning, and it only printed the first element of my linkedlist (and without reversing it). For example, if I didn't pass by reference for a list 1->2->3, I would print out just 1.

I thought passing a pointer would be enough? Why did I get such weird behaviour without passing by reference>

Comment: if you pass pointer by value, you cannot see modification (`head = prev`) of the pointer, whereas by reference you can.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables in C++ (stored in the stack) have block scope, i.e., they run out of scope after the block in which they are defined is executed.

When you are passing in a pointer to the function, a copy of the pointer is created and that copy is what is passed. Once the function is executed, the variables in the function workspace run out of scope. Any non-static Automatic variables created within the function are destroyed.

When you pass in by reference you don't pass in a copy of the variable but you pass in the actual variable, thereby any changes made to the variable are reflected on the actual variable passed into the function(by reference).

I would like to point out that the pointer to the next node is stored in memory and has an address to the location it is stored. So if you want to not pass in by reference you can do this:

1. Use a pointer to the pointer, which points to the memory location at which pointer variable(address) to the next node is stored
2. Pass in this to the function (not by reference)
3. Dereference the pointer and store the new address you want to point to.

I know this is a bit confusing, but look into this small piece of code that adds a node to a linked list.

```
void addNode(Node** head, int newData)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = newData; // Can also be done using (*newNode).data
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by: "Once the function is executed, we are out of the scope of the function"?

Comment: @codekaizer : The memory of a program is divided into segments - data segment, heap, stack,etc. The data is where the initialized global and static variables are stored. Heap is for dynamic memory allocation and stack is where the function parameters, local variables and function related information is stored. When we enter a function, it is allocated certain memory in the stack and within this workspace the variables defined within the function are created. When we exit the function the variables created within the function are deleted(if non-static) and you cannot access it anymore.

Comment: yeah I have switching between MATLAB , C++ and python continuously and just got a bit confused. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Recommending an edit: "Thereby any variables (non-static) created within the function are destroyed." ->"Any non-static Automatic variables  created within the function are destroyed." The original allows for dynamic variables to be destroyed and this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought passing a pointer would be enough?

```
void reverseLinkedList(Node* head) // pass pointer by value
                                   // head is a copy here
```

Passing a `pointer` by value creates a copy to be used inside the function.

Any changes made to that pointer inside the function is only reflected in the function scope. 
Since those changes are only reflected in the pointer's copy and **not** in the original pointer.

Once the `pointer` (copy) goes out of scope, those changes are "discarded" due to end of life.

Thus, you need a reference.

```
void reverseLinkedList(Node&* head) // changes made in head will be
                                    // reflected in original head pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a pointer regularly (IE by value) it creates a copy of the pointer. Any changes made to this pointer do not effect the original pointer.

Passing a pointer by reference is sending a reference to that pointer (very similar to passing a pointer to a pointer) and therefor any changes made to that pointer are effecting its 'original' state.

For example:

```
//WRONG does not modify the original pointer, causes memory-leak.
void init(Object* ptr, int sz) {
    ptr = new T[sz]; 
}
```

vs

```
 //Correct original pointer is a set to a new block of memory
void init(Object*& ptr, int sz) {
    ptr = new T[sz]; 
}
```

Comment: **Bit of a tangent, in practice there is seldom a reason to reverse a doubly-linked list as you may simply iterate through it backwards and save yourself the O(n). Though its always good to practice!

Comment: The above assumes that you have a tail pointer remembering the end of the list. Without it you'll suffer the O(n) finding the end of the list in order to iterate backward.

Comment: Most doubly-linkedlist implementations contain a `Node* last` so you can add to the end of the list in `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

In

```
void reverseLinkedList(Node* head)
```

The pointer is passed by value.

This sounds silly, it's a freaking pointer, right? Kind-of the definition of pass by reference. Well, the `Node` that's being *pointed at* is passed by reference. The *pointer itself*, `head` is just another variable that happens to contain the address of some other variable, and it's *not* being passed by reference.

So `head` contains a copy of the `Node` pointer used to call `reverseLinkedList`, and as with all parameters passed by value, any modifications to the copy, pointing `head` somewhere else, are not represented in the calling function.